# Cannot read property '0' of undefined:Angular

Tags: angular

I've got an input field in the angular form as follows

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload"

                                  ngModel (change)="selectFile($event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" >
```

The method that gets invoked on change

```
selectFile(event){
      console.log("select file method called");

      this.selectedFiles=event.target.files[0];
    }
```

This method is getting invoked on the file selection but  `this.selectedFiles=event.target.files[0];` results in
error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.Even though a file is  selected, why `target.files[0]` results in the error?

Comment: if you put a break point before the assign, what's shown in `event.target.files` ?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Getting the same error.

Comment: I know you get the same error, I asked you to tell me what's inside `event.target.files`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi console.log() shows undefined.

Comment: Alright, and `event` is undefined too?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi No, event is [object Event]

Comment: If you could attach a link that shown the relative `JSON.stringify` of that object it would be amazing.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi console.log(JSON.stringify(event)) shows {"isTrusted":true}

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload"
  ngModel (change)="selectFile($event.target.files)" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" >
```

in ts file

```
selectFile(files: File[]){
    console.log(files)}
```

it will work

Comment: But with this, I can't append `files` to `FormData` ,It results in following error `Argument of type 'File[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'File[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload
go through this example

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FileReader class :)

```
HTML
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" (change)="selectFile($event)">

TS

selectFile(event){
      console.log("select file method called");
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          console.log(e.target.result)
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload"(change)="selectFile($event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" >
```

ts file

```
selectFile(fileInput: any) {
this.selectedFiles = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
 }
```